# Timer not working when using defer in angular

Tags: angular

```
@Input() readonly s!: number
time$ = defer(() => of(this.s)).pipe(
  switchMap((s) => timer(0, 1000).pipe(map((n)=> s - n))),
    takeWhile(n => n >0)
  )
export class timer{
  readonly SECONDS = SECONDS
}
```

```
export const SECONDS = +(
  process.env.SECONDS || 300
)
```

I am trying to make a countdown timer which goes from 5:00,4:59...0:00. When I try to implement this I can only see 0:00 on the screen.

app HTML file

```
<p class="description">
      timer
      <timer
        [s]="SECONDS"
      ></timer>
    </p>
```

Timer HTML file

```
<p>{{ time$ | async | date: 'mm:ss' }} minutes</p>
```

Comment: You’re not using $time anywhere. Cold observables need to be subscribed to by at least one subscriber to begin executing. You’ve got no subscriptions

Comment: @pixelbits I am using timer$ in html file, just updated the question.

Comment: I believe you are using date pipe in a wrong way. it should be used to represent date, not just number

Comment: you forget multiply by 1000:`switchMap((s) => timer(0, 1000).pipe(map((n)=> (s - n)*1000))),`

Comment: @Andrei, it's perfect valid use a number with date pipe (see the Input value in the [docs](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe#input-value)) and it's the best choice when we want to do a count down in minutes and seconds.